# How to return function value only by calling constructor

Tags: javascript

So my javascript class looks like this:

```
class Teams {
    get myteams() {
        return [
            'Man utd',
            'Barcelona'
        ]
    }

    constructor(){
        return this
    }
}

console.log(Array.from(new Teams()).join(','));
```

Without chanving the constructor, how can I print the content of the array in the function "myteams"?

Note that the constructor has to remain untouched. Also, I cannot add anything in the console.log. The changes need to be made inside the class.

***Correct answer***

Well, actually it was my fault not explaining it better. However, I found the solution, which was quite simple. Basically it was about declaring at the beginning pf the class this variable:

```
    this = this.get;
```

Then it will be enough to only calling "new Teams" which will return the data from the getter method.

Comment: 1. You don't need to explicitly return `this` from a constructor. 2. Why `Array.from`?

Comment: What's actually the question? Why is there a `return this` in the constructor?

Comment: I updated the question. This is a test where it is required to leave constructor untouched. Only things that can be changed are function inside the class. Thats why the code looks strange. Honestly I have never heard about executing a class function without calling it.

Comment: I've added clarity to arthurs second answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
console.log(new Teams().myteams.join(","));
```

You are trying to get an array from the actual Teams object, but the array only returned in the getter 'myteams', so you have to access that getter.

#### // -- Edit: For clarity sake --

You don't need to return anything in the constructor, in-fact you shouldn't.

```
class Teams {
  get myteams() {
    return [
        'Man utd',
        'Barcelona'
    ]
  }
}
```

Would really be all you need to make the above code work.

Now do you want to be able to edit properties after construction like so:

```
class Teams {
  constructor( teams ){
    this.myteams = teams
  }
}
const teams = new Teams( [ 'Man utd', 'Barcelona'] )
teams.myteams.push("FC Bacelona")
console.log( teams.myteams.join(", ") )
```

OR did you just mean you want an object literal that you can access and change at will: ( which could also be a getter )

```
const teams = {
    myteams: ['Man utd', 'Barcelona']
}
const teams2 = {
    get myteams(){
      return [
        'Man utd',
        'Barcelona'
      ]
    }
}
teams.myteams.push("FC Barcelona") // no error
console.log( teams.myteams.join(", ") ) // 'Man utd', Barcelona', 'FC Barcelona'
teams2.myteams.push("...") // throws error
// say you catch the above error, you fancy guy
console.log( teams2.myteams.join(", ") ) // 'Man utd', Barcelona', 'FC Barcelona'
```

Best of luck ( Sorry for hijacking your correct answer to explain on a wrongly closed question, it was my only recourse, good news, you'll get the credit)

Comment: I should have been specified that. Of course there are very simple ways to do this. But given that the constructor has to remain intouched, how do I return the array only modifying the class (but not the constructor)

Comment: Uhm.... you made it a getter... why? That's not something you modify at all...

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you're doing this but `return this.myteams` in your constructor should work.
your method myteams returns an array so your last line sould simply be `console.log(new Teams());`.

Comment: Well of course. But its some kind of test where it is required to let constructor untouched.